# How to resolve VS Code variables in extension context?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How to resolve VS Code variables defined in [`launch.json`/`tasks.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) inside an extension?

I'm writing an extension which has a class that implements `vscode.DebugConfigurationProvider`, and I'm looking to get the actual values of variables like `${file}` inside a `debugConfiguration` before passing the debug configuration to the debug adapter.

The reason behind this is because our extension is only propagating the debug requests to language-specific debugging extensions like `vscode-cpptools`, and `vscode-python`, so we need to process the debug requests inside `resolveDebugConfiguration()`.

It’d be really helpful if we could get pointed to the code/module that handles the resolving process! Thanks in advance =)

Comment: just wondering if there is any other way than to use `vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri` when the property is equal to `"${file}"`